# how to validate my form field after my check box is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

i have created one form with dynamically created fields. and i have a one check box with unique ID . when user clicks that check box  then only those two fields are visible ("name and age"). after clicking only "age" field need to  be validate .

here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#person').click(function() {
        function formValidator(){
            var age = document.getElementsByName('age[]');
            for (var i = 0; i< age.length; i++) {
                if(!isNumeric(age[i], "Please enter a valid Age")){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
            var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
                return true;
            } else {
                alert(helperMsg);
                elem.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
   });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#person').click(function() {
        $('#name').attr('required','required');
        $('#age').attr('required','required');
    });
});
```

style is :

```css
.selectContainer{
    display:none;
 }

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .selectContainer {
    display:block;
}
```

Html code is:

```html
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return formValidator()">
    <label for="name">Any Accompanying Person ?:</label>
    <input  type="checkbox" name="person" id="person" >Yes
    <div class="selectContainer">
        <br>
        <label>Person Details</label>
        <p>
            <div style="padding-left:70px;"> 
                <input type="button" value="Add Person" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /> 
            </div>
        </p>
        <table style="padding-left:50px;" id="dataTable" class="form" border="1"  >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" size="20" name="name[]" id="name"   >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Age</label>
                            <input type="text" size="20" name="age[]" id="age"  >
                        </td>
                    </p>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
<h3>Choose Your Payment Option</h3>
<h1>
<div style="padding-left:150px;">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="visa">VISA/MASTER CARD:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="cheque"> CHEQUE/DEMAND DRAFT<br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="neft">NEFT<br /><br/>
</div>
<label></label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br />
</form>
```

problem: the form field "age" is validating successfully by clicking check box ("Any Accompanying Person ?:"). problem is when user try to submit the form without clicking that check box then all so its asking for validate . how get salutation for this ? please help

Comment: It would help if you fix the code indenting. You are trying to call *formValidator* as a global from the *submit* handler, however it's declared inside the function passed to `$('#person').click()` so not accessible.

Comment: then what is the salutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator is within a click handler, which should live outside of that (On the base on the document.ready()).

Also if you just want to validate when that checkbox is clicked you could check it within the javascript and select it via the name of the checkbox (If it has a unique ID each time).

```
function formValidator(){
    var age = document.getElementsByName('age[]');
    if($("input[name = 'chk[]']").prop('checked')){
        for (var i = 0; i< age.length; i++) {
            if(!isNumeric(age[i], "Please enter a valid Age")){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can replace `$("input[name = 'chk[]']").prop('checked')` with `age.form['chk[]'].checked`.

Comment: Well you learn something new each day :).  That's a lot simpler.

Comment: how about my required field .that's all so having same problem .how to fix that ?

Comment: The name and age inputs?  If you also want them required you could check if they have values within the formValidator.  If they have unique Ids you could use the same css selector except name = 'name[]' and name = 'age[]', then do a `if(!$("input[name = 'name[]']").val()){ return false; }`

Answer (score 0):

Bring all javascript functions outside of click events. Try this formValidator function

```js
function formValidator(){

        if($("#person").is(":checked")) {

   var age = document.getElementsByName('age[]');
    for (var i = 0; i< age.length; i++) {
  if(!isNumeric(age[i], "Please enter a valid Age")){
    return false;
  }
    }

        }

 return true;
     }
```